# I want to run a task every day at 8 AM using Android alarm manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm using this code but I'm unable to do so. 
There is no error in this code but it is not triggering the alarm:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8); 
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, Home.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Comment: What exactly is the Home class you're mentioning in the intent here?

Comment: okey i got that so there should be the receiver class right..?

Comment: I am first asking what Home is, since it's not detailed in the code given here.

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46397527/5095571, it's discussing using AlarmManager to send an sms automatically but quickly reviews the steps and possible pitfalls in scheduling a task to be performed daily.